# IF Python ( Not Clip )

Tags: python, if-statement

thanks to support as i have excel sheet with data mostly number that imported to python pandas . column " Stuff time " which contain Number that need to make (if function) in it as if number is less than 14400 put 0 & if number >32400 put 32400 if not will put the exist number ex:

below how it's done in excel that i want in python

```
1-33181 = ( if(33181 <14400,0 ,if  33181 >32400,32400 , 33181 ) = 33181
2-12000 = ( if(12000 <14400,0 ,if  12000 >32400,32400 , 12000 ) = 12000
```

i need to add column lets call it ( New Stuff time ) with cacaltion to be applied in raw more that 10000 rows

to put more clear view condition in excel if ( number )<14400 ,( Zero ) , if ( number )>32400 , 32400 , ( put the number that exist )

i tried to use Clip but it was wrong as if number <14400 it will be 14400 not zero

Edit

Data as in excel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKw4U.png)

- Staff Time , is the original time
- New Stuff Time , is what i made by using function if in excel that

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think it would be helpful if you could provide a *real* Excel formula with column references. It's  not clear to me if `33181` is supposed to be a cell reference or an integer literal. Excel formulas are supposed to begin with `=`. These don't.  I'm  sure it's very clear to you what you have in mind but I have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: `df[ df["Stuff time"] < 14400 ] = 0` and `df[ df["Stuff time"] > 32400 ] = 32400`

Comment: maybe better show example data (as DataFrame) and expected result. And don't put data as image.

Comment: if you need it in new column then first you can copy this column `df["New Stuff time"] = df["Stuff time"]` and later run `df[ df["New Stuff time"] < 14400 ] = 0` and `df[ df["New Stuff time"] > 32400 ] = 32400`

Comment: many thanks for showing support from all of you , in excel i'm using below function (  consider A2 as the cell that i need to change ) =IF(A2<14400;0;IF(A2>32400;32400;A2))

Comment: you can always run `apply()` with your function which replace values - `df["New Stuff time"] = df["Stuff time"].apply(your_function)` and `def your_function(value): ...if/else... return new_value`

Comment: I'm really grateful :-) many thanks , i use the below & it's worked well .                 
 def New_stuff (X,h,l):
    if X < h :
        return(0)
    if X > l :
        return(32400)  
    return(X)
Df5["New Stuff time"] = Df5["Staffed Time"].apply(New_stuff , args=[14400,32400])
Df5.to_excel('modified.xlsx' , index=False)

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to everyone , the below is the answer i was looking for

```
def New_stuff (X,h,l):
    if X < h :
        return(0)
    if X > l :
        return(32400)  
    return(X)
Df5["New Stuff time"] = Df5["Staffed Time"].apply(New_stuff , args=[14400,32400])
Df5.to_excel('modified.xlsx' , index=False)
```